# C# | How to call a MVC Data Access Layer through AWS Lambda function

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We have a AWS Lambda function which will trigger whenever a new file comes under the S3 bucket, but we need to log the activities in our existing MySQL DB by using our existing MVC Application project. So that we don't need to write down the Logging mechanism. Please help me out, I am new in this world.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We solve it through API, We first trigger our Lambda function and in that we are calling our MVC Web API (Which is available under our existing web solution) and in that Web API we are calling our Data Access Layer database logging.